# Windows 10 stuck at restarting screen after successfully upgraded from v1511 to v1607

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, windows-10-v1607

After I successfully upgraded from Windows 10 v1511 to v1607, aka Anniversary update, my system gets stuck at the restarting screen whenever I want to restart my system. Always.

Turning my computer off, on the other side, **works**, as long as "fast boot" (aka "hybrid boot" or "hybrid shutdown") is enabled. As soon as I disable "fast boot", my system gets stuck at the shutdown screen, too.

Booting into safe mode and restating works.

I tried to reset windows update (as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3bfhxk/windows_10_gets_stuck_on_the_restarting_screen/csm23ce)), but it didn't help.

---

- Did anyone have a similar issue and knows a possible solution?

*or*

- Do you have any idea how I could take a look at what's actually going on here? Are there any logfiles etc. which tell me "process X blocked Windows", or the last action Windows was trying to do is to close process X? I tried event log, but didn't find any useful information there.

---

Update: It's most probable not a (third-party) driver issue. I disabled any non-Microsoft driver except my display driver. I verified with [DriverView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html) that no third-party driver except Nvidia was active. But the issue remains.

Comment: If restarting works while in Safe Mode, the behavior is caused by a incompatible driver, have you determined which driver is causing this behavior?

Comment: Do you have Bitlocker/TPM?

Comment: No Bitlocker or TPM. / I already tried to disable some exotic third-party drivers (like Sandboxie or RAMDisk), but those didn't cause this issue. I'm still researching.

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried to disabled any single third-party driver (see update) but the issue remains.

Comment: @manuel - So you tried the drivers.  How about third-party applications?

Comment: @Ramhound: well, if it was a userspace application, I would get a "Waiting for Background Program to Close" error message, but I don't. It could be a service though, therefore I disabled any third-party service via. msconfig. And to be sure I uninstalled every low-level software like antivirus, RAMDisk, and driver utilities, but the issue remains. I think I have to switch back to v1511 and defer the upgrade until Microsoft gets its act together. I have heard that Anniversary update is well known for causing all kinds of issues.

Comment: @manuel - Before you revert back to Version 1511, you should attempt to a boot configuration, where no third-party software is started.  Since you have confirmed, that if booted into Safe Mode, the behavior does not exhbit itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. First of all, there is actually a way to precisely look at what's going on during shutdown. Windows has a switch to become verbose! [Enable Verbose or Highly Detailed Status Messages In Windows 10/8/7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows)

Armed with this technique, I gave it another try and I found out that group policy service was responsible for the hang, and from there I found that [it's most likely a shutdown script](https://serverfault.com/questions/33507/troubleshooting-windows-2008-shutdown-issue). And indeed, I've set a shutdown script changing some registry keys some time ago. I'm not exactly sure what the problem with this was, maybe Windows added a feature so that "reg add" was waiting confirmation before overwriting (that never came), but after disabling the script, my problem was solved.

However, it's still a mystery why this issue didn't occur on "hybrid boot". Does Windows not execute shutdown scripts when "hybrid boot" is enabled? Or is there a hard timeout that's not there when doing a full shutdown? Mysterious...